# How to run selenium tests with 200+ parallel browser on EC2 instance

Tags: selenium-webdriver, aws, parallel-execution

I have implemented parallel execution of Selenium tests and my requirement is to run the tests with 200+ parallel Chrome browsers.

I am running my scripts on an EC2 instance in headless mode. The EC2 instance config is 8-core CPU and 32GB memory, which is less for 200+ browsers. I don't want to increase the config as it will increase the cost.

Can anyone suggest some AWS setup to achieve parallel execution so that I can use the AWS instance on demand and destroy it if not in use thereby saving cost?

Comment: Have you checked AWS Device Farm?

Comment: no I haven't checked AWS Device Farm. Thanks for the suggestion, let me check if it suits my requirement

Comment: AWS device farm only allows 50 parallel sessions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/testgrid/techref-limits.html

Comment: Just like any AWS service you can just ask the support to increase the limit as stated in the docs. "If you require more than 50 concurrent sessions, open a technical support case with your use case"

Comment: it is written that they can approve or reject the request. There are other restrictions as well like - 
1. You may create up to 5 sessions per second.
2. You may call createTestGridUrl up to 10 times a second etc

Comment: As I mentioned, the doc says you can request to increase those limits.

Comment: An alternative is running a bunch of spot instances, run your tests and dispose them (This might scale for much more than 200 parallel instances). There's an example on AWS blog here: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/opensource/run-selenium-tests-at-scale-using-aws-fargate/

Comment: thanks @AndréRoggeriCampos, this might help. We are also designing something on the similar lines. Thanks for the help!